# Diferença entre repeater_itemdatabound e repeater_itemcommand

Tags: c#, asp.net

Qual a aplicabilidade e diferença entre repeater_itemdatabound e repeater_itemcommand em um repeater?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe bastante diferença, e entenda o porque:

**Repeater_ItemDataBound**

Este evento está associado a vinculação dos dados na hora de renderizar a página, ou seja, ocorre durante a construção do `Repeater`. É basicamente o evento construtor do repeater.

**Repeater_ItemCommand**

Este evento está associado a uma açãoa que ocorrerá a partir de um elemento dentro do repeater, ou seja, pode estar vinculado ao `click` de um botão dentro do repeater. São eventos realizados após o *Repeater ItemDataBound*.

[MSDN - Repeater ItemCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)
[MSDN - Repaeter ItemDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound(v=vs.110).aspx)